# Sound of maze generating not working when i try to run it

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, maze

I am trying to use sound of maze generation(https://github.com/odedw/sound-of-maze-generation) but whenever i try to run it i get an error.

It always says it exits with code (0x800703e9) or stack overflow or a driver is not installed and no matter how hard i try, i cannot get it to work.

I cant replicate the errors, since i have tried to edit it with absolutely no c# programming knowledge and i forgot what i edited.

Sorry for making it so short but it is my first post so i don't know how to do it.

Comment: "I cant replicate the errors, since i have tried to edit it with absolutely no c# programming knowledge and i forgot what i edited." ...so, download the code again from the original and run that? Or do you mean it was your edited version which generates errors? It's not entirely clear.

Comment: Anyway we are going to need to see a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before anyone can help you. We cannot diagnose a problem based on vague descriptions of errors, and uncertainty over which code actually causes the errors. Please provide an accurate code sample, and accurate, complete error messages. Also please tell us what platform you are running this code on.

Comment: As noted you must provide at least the code snippet in question and the exception in order for anyone to try and answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a go, and it also failed on my machine. It turns out that the author was relying some specific audio hardware. See line 85 in the file [ViewModel.cs](https://github.com/odedw/sound-of-maze-generation/blob/master/SoundOfMazeGeneration/ViewModel.cs):

```
_asio = new AsioOut("Focusrite USB ASIO");
```

However, there is also a `WaveOut` mechanism (in the same file), currently commented out.

When I "commented away" all `_asio` references and "revived" the `waveOut` mechanism it did start successfully (and produced sound) (i.e. noise ;-).

(You only need to make changes to this particular file.)